# Как использовать две библиотеки jQuery (1.6.2 и 1.3.2)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Вообщем столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть скрипт голосования, он работает на 1.3.2, но на 1.6.2 глюки. А все остальные штучки стабильно работают на 1.6.2 (если использовать 1.3.2, то половина плагинов работать не будет). Что предпринять, не знаю.

Вот ссылка с мануалом по голосованию: [AJAX User Poll Using jQuery and PHP](http://webdeveloperplus.com/php/ajax-user-poll-using-jquery-and-php/).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: перепишите!

Comment: мда там в коде все вроде бы нормально, но однако не работает

Comment: а в чём проявляются глюки?

Comment: не двигается бар(если посмотреть код в браузере то можно увидеть что там установлено Display:none; и длина бара в пикселах а не в процентах)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечу на исходный вопрос.
Надо чтобы ваша либа использовала старый Jquery.

Для начала нужно подключить старую версию библиотеки.

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2"></script>
```

После чего снять бинд с переменной $

```
var OLD_JQUERY = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Теперь подключаем новую версию

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2"></script>
```

Cкрипт нужно обернуть в конструкцию вида

```
(function($) {
  // тут ваш скрипт
})(OLD_JQUERY )
```

Тогда он будет использовать старую версию.

Comment: merci man  все работает! хотя переработать на новую версию не помешало бы

Comment: Ну если на вопрос я ответил, то стоит пометить ответ как верный. А про переработку кода под новую версию лучше создать новый вопрос ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли проблема кроется в версиях библиотек jQuery. Насколько я знаю, начиная с 1.3.2 по 1.6.2 не было введено в ядро ничего фундаментального, так, что проблема тут вряд ли в разнице версиях...

Comment: нет именно версии попробуйте запустите этот плагин с версией 1.6.2 работать не будет

Comment: проверил еще раз работает до версии 1.4.2(1.4.3 не работает)касательно википедии процитирую "1.4.2 - 19 февраля 2010 Добавлены новые методы .delegate() и .undelegate()[9], Улучшения производительности вызова .bind() и .unbind(), производительность .empty(), .remove() и .html(), также улучшена производительность добавления единичного DOM узла и вызова $("body")."
"1.4.3 - 16 октября 2010 Многочисленные изменения."

Answer (score 0):

А если использовать [.noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)?

Comment: пробовал не получилось(лучший вариант все таки переписать плагин или изменить его)

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/ смотрели?

Comment: нет это не смотрел спс щас посмотрю

Comment: не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Люди я нашел проблему 
исходный код проблема была такая - width:"ширина в пикселах px" display:none;

```
function animateResults(data){
$(data).find('.bar').hide().end().fadeIn('slow', function(){
$(this).find('.bar').each(function(){
var bar_width=$(this).css('width');
$(this).css('width', '0').animate({ width: bar_width }, 1000);
});
});
}
```

отредактировал так

```
function animateResults(data){
      $(data).find('.bar').hide().end().fadeIn('slow', function(){
            $(this).find('.bar').each(function(){
                  var bar_width=parseInt($(this).prev().find('em').text());
                  $(this).css('width', '0%').show().animate({ width: bar_width + '%' }, 1000);
            });
      });
}
```

теперь параметры встали как надо но только display:block; и теперь стали проценты но там всегда 0

еще отредактировал стало так

```
 function animateResults(data){
          $(data).find('.bar').hide().end().fadeIn('slow', function(){
                $(this).find('.bar').each(function(){
                      var bar_width=parseInt($(this).prev().find('em').text());
                      $(this).show().animate({ width: bar_width + '%' }, 1000);
                });
          });
    }
```

но исчезла анимация(плавная) баров теперь она появляется резко(решить эту проблему пока не удалось)

если кто знает как подскажите