# Несовместимость версий JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fancybox

Здравствуйте! Объясните пожалуйста, что делать в данном случае: есть слайдер, которые требует определённую версию JQuery и FancyBox, который соответственно тоже требует определённую версию JQuery. И эти две версии - несовместимы, остаётся работать что то одно, а другое выдаёт ошибку мол в данной версии JQuery нет нужной функции. Что в данной ситуации делать? Спасибо

Comment: выкинуть все нахрен и использовать плагины (слайдер и попап), которые не заброшены 5 лет назад.

Comment: @Владимир, старая версия fancybox - http://fancybox.net/ , новая - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137798/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-jquery-1-6-2-%D0%B8-1-3-2